# Why wont the vector be empty?

Tags: c++, vector

I am wondering why this wont recognize the vector is empty and supply vector pStack with double start? The object of the program is just to simply supply the stack vector with 50 the first time around when it is empty. Then once it is supplied with the starting amount it should subtract with the user input  (being bet). Then since its a vector it carries over the old sum into the 2nd time around so it can be subtracted with the user input of bet again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class Bet
{
public:
   void set_stack(double n);
   void set_bet(double n);
   double analyze();
   double get_stack();
   double get_bet();

private:
   double pCount;
   double bet;
};

double Bet::analyze()
{
   double p = pCount;
   double b = bet;
   double z = p - b;
   return z;
}

void Bet::set_bet(double n)
{
   bet = z;
}

double Bet::get_bet()
{
   return bet;
}

void Bet::set_stack(double n)
{
   pCount = n;
}

double Bet::get_stack()
{
   return pCount;
}


double start = 50; // Start needs to go inside of pStack
double bbet;
vector<double> pStack(1);


int main()
{
   bool con = true;
   while(con){
      if(pStack.empty()){
         pStack.push_back(start); // pStack should be supplied with start when empty
      }

      double adjst = pStack[0];

      Bet rr;
      rr.set_stack(adjst);
      pStack.clear();
      cout << "Enter min 1 Bet: ";
      cin >> bbet;
      rr.set_bet(bbet);

      double aStack = rr.analyze();
      pStack.push_back(aStack); 
      rr.set_stack(aStack);
      double newStack = rr.get_stack();

      cout << "Stack: " << newStack << endl;
      cout << "Bet: " << bbet << endl;
   }

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The absence of indentation makes it more difficult than necessary to read your code.

Comment: You are explicitly constructing a non-empty vector and then asking people here why it is not empty... Why did you use that `(1)` as an initializer for your `pStack`?

Answer (score 4):

```
vector<double> pStack(1);
```

You are initializing your vector with it having an initial size of 1, that's why your `pStack.empty()` check returns `false`.

Do this instead to make its initial state empty.

```
vector<double> pStack;
```

Also, remove the `empty()` check and hoist your `push_back` outside your while loop.

```
bool con = true;
pStack.push_back(start);

while(con){
   ...
```

You might also want to reconsider your usage of global variables. As far as I can see, you can just put `start`, `bbet` and `pStack` inside `main()`.

Comment: Thanks, but now it says the vector subscript is out of range

Comment: @RoadRash then you're logic for using your stack was wrong from the outset. This answer is correct in properly declaring an empty initial stack, and you should examine how you're using your stack for a possibly-unconsidered under-run condition.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the fill constructor. This line will initialize the vector to 1 element, default constructed.

```
vector<double> pStack(1);
```

If you wanted the vector to start out empty, you should just use the default constructor.

```
vector<double> pStack;
```

Comment: "You could also use empty parenthesis, but they're redundant" It wouldn't be redundant; It would be wrong. It would declare a function called `pStack` that returned a `vector<double>` and took no parameters. The correct decl is exactly as you have it.

Comment: Alternatively, use the fill constructor with the initial value: `vector<double> pStack(1, start);`

Comment: Interesting Tristan. Never knew there was such a thing as a fill constructor for a vector.

Answer (score 2):

When you define the `pStack` vector you use the constructor that takes an integer that represent the number of elements to allocate.

```
vector<double> pStack(1);
```

As a result your vector will have 1 default-initialized element.

To create an empty vector do this:

```
vector<double> pStack;
```

Comment: "Number of elements to allocate" usually means capacity, not size. This ctor actually creates elements. I think you should clear it up.